# Can't find the bug in my JS code

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a final array which holds summed numbers of objects with months and merge the same months and sum their itemCount.

Z array is from the Chrome's console:

```
0: Object
itemCount: 6
month: "Aug"

1: Object
itemCount: 0
month: "Jun"

2: Object
itemCount: 0
month: "Sep"

3: Object
itemCount: 0
month: "Sep"
```

and the code I wrote to sum itemCount in months and merge if there are same months:

```
let counterCurrItem = 0, month, 
        finalArr = [], itemCount = 0

    for (i = 0; i < Z.length; i++) {
        month = Z[i].month
        itemCount = Z[i].itemCount
        if (Z[i + 1] !== undefined) {
            if (month == Z[i + 1].month) {
                counterCurrItem = counterCurrItem + itemCount
            } else {
                finalArr.push([counterCurrItem, month])
            }
        } else {
            finalArr.push([counterCurrItem, month])
        }
    }
```

However the final array is not holding the expected values, I expect it to have its first array as [6, 'Aug'] but it is [0, 'Aug'].

So where the problem is in my code?

Some notes: Months are always sorted alphabetically and Z array will always have more than 1 object in it.

Comment: have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle with (faulted) result and expected result?

Comment: Why do you expect that result? I don't, from looking at the code. What is it that would make `counterCurrItem` be `6`?

Comment: @Pete **no**, that is not necessary.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because `Z[i+1]` is never equal to `Z[i]` so you don't increment `counterCurrItem` and so it remains 0.

Comment: As @DanielA.White mentioned, this would be a perfect situation to get to know a debugger.  Chrome developer tools, for example, allows breakpoints and stepping through code.

Comment: and for future questions, please create a more descriptive title than 'can't find the bug...'

Comment: @EricPhillips Thanks for the advice, and I'd like to see something as an example for myself. So what title you would have created for such a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add items like so `finalArr.push([counterCurrItem, month])` but the variable `counterCurrItem` is added in the `if` statement, so it never increments;

Also, you should create a temporary variable in the loop rather than outside the loop so that you don't get incorrect data.

Making the least changes:

```
let counterCurrItem = 0, month, 
    finalArr = [], itemCount = 0

for (i = 0; i < Z.length; i++) {
    month = Z[i].month
    itemCount = Z[i].itemCount
    if (Z[i + 1] && month == Z[i + 1].month ) {
        counterCurrItem = counterCurrItem + itemCount
        finalArr.push([counterCurrItem, month])
    } else {
        finalArr.push([itemCount, month])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  if (month == Z[i + 1].month) {
                counterCurrItem = counterCurrItem + itemCount
            } else {
                finalArr.push([counterCurrItem + itemCount, month]) <<<<
            }
```

Logic problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this:

1)

```
if (month == Z[i + 1].month)
```

You only compare current element's month to the next one's. You should compare it to all of the next elements.

2) You define  counterCurrItem in the if-else statement. Define it before if-else.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution using reductions:

```
var monthMap = Z.reduce(function ( acc, record ) {
        if (!acc[record.month]) acc[record.month] = 0;
        acc[record.month] += record.itemCount;
        return acc;
    }, {}),
    finalAry = Object.keys(monthMap).reduce(function ( ary, key ) {
        ary.push([monthMap[key], key);
        return ary;
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so read the code through.

It gets item 1 [6, Aug].

```
month = Z[i].month //this is Aug
itemCount = Z[i].itemCount // This is 6

Z[i + 1] // This is not undefined

month == Z[i + 1].month // Aug is not equal to Jun
```

so it calls:

```
finalArr.push([counterCurrItem, month]) // counterCurrItem is not defined so will become 0
```

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't set counterCurrItem when there aren't two consecutive months (like in aug for example) so it will read 0 because that's what it was initialised to.

```
// change this
if (month == Z[i + 1].month) {
    counterCurrItem = counterCurrItem + itemCount
} else {
    finalArr.push([counterCurrItem, month])
}

// to this:          
if (month == Z[i + 1].month) {
    counterCurrItem = counterCurrItem + itemCount
} else {
    finalArr.push([itemCount, month]); // changed!!
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a script that will work regardless of the number of equal months, or sorting.

Explanation is in the code comments:

```
Z = [
  {itemCount: 1, month: 'Sep'},
  {itemCount: 6, month: 'Aug'},
  {itemCount: 0, month: 'Jun'},
  {itemCount: 2, month: 'Sep'}
];

let counterCurrItem = 0,
  month,
  finalArr = [],
  searchArr = [], // search array, will hold objects with their month as a key
  itemCount = 0;

// Loop over all elements in the original array
Z.forEach(function(obj, i) {
  // Get the current object's properties
  month = obj.month;
  itemCount = obj.itemCount;

  // See if the current month has been added to the search array
  if (searchArr[month] === undefined) {
    // First time we see this month, so add it to the final array and the search array
    finalArr.push(obj);
    searchArr[month] = obj;
  }
  else {
    // We had this month before, so loop over the final array, find the month, and update it's count
    for (var j = 0; j < finalArr.length; j++) {
        if (finalArr[j].month === month) {
        finalArr[j].itemCount += itemCount;
      }
    }
  }
});

console.log(finalArr);
```

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/97y988m2/4/